# Show message for insert and update data in index view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, we have

```
public ActionResult Create(parameters)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {  
        //code block 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }                                                 
}
```

This is the method for data insert:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {  
        //code block 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }                                                 
}
```

and I also have a method for data edit.

On successful insert/edit, I am calling

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I want to show a message "data inserted successfully" for `create` method and "data updated successfully" for `update` method.

Is it possible to show such a message on the `Index` page, or is there any other way I can show message to the user for these two successful operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. There is no problem to pass a string as a model to the view**:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    return View((object)message);
}

public ActionResult Create(/*parameters*/)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code block 
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { message = "Data inserted successfully" });
    }
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code block 
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { message = "Data updated successfully" });
    }
    return View();
}
```

And the `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model System.String

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var text = (Model is string) ? Model : String.Empty;
}

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>@Model</h1>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home" /* route values */))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new { id = 123 }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

**2. And it's possible to pass message in the `TempData`**:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    TempData["message"] = message;
    return View((object)message);
}
```

In the view:

```
@{
    var message = (TempData.ContainsKey("message") && TempData["message"] is string msg) ? msg : String.Empty;
    ViewBag.Title = "Index Page";
}

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>@Model</h1>
    </div>
}
```

**3. A message string might be included to the view model of the strongly typed view.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use toastr .... here is the example with detail

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97d5a6/toastr-notifications-to-your-web-site/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use **TempData** to pass a message to a View.  You can set the value of **TempData** right before the RedirectToAction:

```
TempData["message"] = "data inserted successfully";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

In the Index view, the message will only be displayed if **TempData** was set in the controller:

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert-info">@TempData["message"]</div>
}
```